# How can I convert bytearray of an image to RTMP live streaming using FFmpeg or other tools?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, byte

I have a stream from a source, that give me byte array for each frame,I konw how to convert jpeg files to rtmp by using ffmpeg,  but I don't know how to use ffmpeg to convert byte array to rtmp streaming.
BTW, I use java.
Thanks.

Comment: The input looks to be rawvideo. As long as ffmpeg recognizes or is told the input parameters, you can encode and stream it like any other input.

Comment: Oh yeah,the input is video file or cam stream(rtsp).The problem is that I don't want to save every frame  to local after I process it ,  because I think it's kind of inefficiency.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For a faster Answer.. Please [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43224890/edit) your question to include what you've tried so far. For example, are you using a `ProcessBuilder` or maybe importing some FFmpeg API library? Nobody knows... If you **show some code** then we can see how you're building and help you with that (if possible). At least show your code for jpeg-to-rtmp and then someone can show how to adjust that for bytearray-to-rtmp...